# How to redirect cloudfront url to main domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-cloudfront

Is there any way to redirect cloudfront url https://abcdefghijk.cloudfront.net to main domain https://www.example.com ?

Comment: Please edit this question to clarify whether example.com is the origin domain name or the CloudFront alternate domain name, as well as whether you only want to redirect requests with the path set to `/` as shown here, or if you actually want to redirect regardless of the request path.

Answer (score 1):

AWS docs have entire sections dedicated to how one could setup a custom URL's in place of CloudFront's default URLs, including setting up HTTPS:

- [Using Custom URLs for Files by Adding Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html)
- [Using Alternate Domain Names and HTTPS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https-alternate-domain-names.html)